# How to capture image from webcam in python2?

Tags: python-2.7, webcam, raspberry-pi3

The code that I have used gives the output but the image is cropped randomly and does not fit tot the size of the window. When i use  `namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);`  it gives the error as 
:`NameError: name 'CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE'` is not defined

Code:

```
from cv2 import *
# initialize the camera
cam = VideoCapture(0)   # 0 -> index of camera
s, img = cam.read()
if s:    # frame captured without any errors
    namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("cam-test",img)
    waitKey(500)
    destroyWindow("cam-test")
    imwrite("filename.jpg",img) #save image
```

what should i do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shZDt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
```

to:

```
namedWindow("Image");
```